# How to specify asciidoc to use local directory for stylesheet within the document?

Tags: asciidoc

I can make asciidoc use the local directory for the stylesheet by using the full path:

```
:stylesheet: /this/complicated/path/my.css
```

But I want to make my document both self-contained and movable. Is there a way to specify that I want it to use the file `my.css` from the same directory where the `.adoc` file is located?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not specify a path, the stylesheet is assumed to be in the same directory as the document:

```
:stylesheet: my.css
```

See: https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#applying-a-theme

Comment: It looks like the behaviour is different between asciidoc and asciidoctor. I find out the former needs `:linkcss:` to have that same behaviour.